# struts2 variable only being called once in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, struts2, tags

I have my action class with a method that that increments an index every time it is called.

```
private int index = -1;
public String getName() {
    setIndex();
    return myDataSet.elementAt(getIndex()).toString();
}

public void setIndex() {this.index = index+1;}

public int getIndex() {return index;}
```

I call this method with a struts tag

```
<s:property value="name" />
```

when it's in static html it works fine. but when I use the javascript document.write in a loop it only gets called the first time and then uses that value every time.

```
function drawNameList(){
    for(var i = 0; i < numbOfNames; i++)
    {
        document.write('<s:property value="name" />');
    }
}
```

is there some way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider what is interpreted in the client browser (javascript) and what is a template to be filled in server (struts 2 tags)

Your `<s:property value="name" />` is evaluated only once, in your server application.  Then an HTML page is rendered and sent to the client, with that value substituted already (let's say its value is "Stackoverflow").  This is the only call to your method.

Once arrived to client browser, the javascript engine executes the `document.write('Stackoverflow')` fragment as many times as necessary, but there is no further communication with the server, nor calls to your method.

Comment: ah, so if I use javascript I'm screwed. perhaps building a quick java method on the page might work?

Comment: What you need is to render the appropiate HTML in the server side.  Consider exposing your Vector of data as getNames() in your struts 2 action, and then use the iterator tag:

http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/iterator.html